# Stepped Line with angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for generating some charts dynamically with data from my backend.

What I haven't found documentation on and no one seems to have asked so far is **how to create a graph with a stepped line** like chart.js features it [here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/2.6.0/charts/line/stepped.html).

I haven't found information about if this is supported yet.

What I tried is the following:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

And the JS:

```
    $scope.data = {
        type: 'line',
        datasets: [{
            steppedLine: true,
            data: countdata,
            fill: false
        }]
    }
    $scope.labels = countlabels;
```

This is not working, the graph doesn't show up. If I only pass the `countdata` array then it works: `$scope.data = countdata;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of chart is well supported.

The reason it's not working is because, you are configuring the chart in an inappropriate way. `$scope.data` should be an array of dataset­*(s)*, not an object, and that's the reason it's working when you set `$scope.data = countdata`

To add additional properties for the dataset­*(s)*, you need to set those inside `$scope.datasetOverride` like so ...

```
$scope.datasetOverride = [{
   steppedLine: true,
   fill: false
}];
```

Here is a [**working example on plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bfme72nDwO2PohO3kAZX?p=preview)

Comment: Ah I see! I checked the source of the demo and it passed it with an object there, not via datasetOverride. Interesting. Thanks'

Answer (score 0):

```
    lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [85, 72, 78, 75, 77, 75], label: 'Crude oil prices' },
  ];

  lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['01.01.2021', '05.01.2021', '15.01.2021', '25.01.2021', '27.01.2021', '31.01.2021'];


  lineOptions: ChartLineOptions= {
    // stepped:true,
  }

  elementChartOptions: ChartElementsOptions = {
    line: this.lineOptions,
  };

  lineChartOptions = {
    // responsive: true,
    steppedLine: true,
    fill: false,
    elements: this.elementChartOptions
  };



  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.28)',
    },
  ];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartPlugins = [];
  lineChartType = 'line';
```

chartlineoptions should be set as stepped and this configuration should be added cascaded. After that, options should be given [options] at HTML side

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
            <canvas baseChart [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType"
                [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
            </canvas>
 </div>
```